# CPP to Python Communication Issue - Getting stuck before acquiring ThreadState

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

We are trying to have a simple program which will communicate from  a cpp to python 
This is our code (modified for simplicity)
    #include "iostream"
    #include

```
using namespace std;

PyInterpreterState* _InterpState=NULL;

class APPNAME_PyLock
{
public:
    /// Acquire the lock
    APPNAME_PyLock(bool lock = true)
        : _lock(lock)
    {
        cout<<"Inside APPNAME_PyLock () function    CPlock1"<<endl;
        if (_lock)
        {
            cout<<"CPlock2"<<endl;
                _threadState = PyThreadState_New(_InterpState);         
                cout<<"CPlock3"<<endl;
            PyEval_AcquireThread(_threadState);
            cout<<"CPlock4"<<endl;
        }
    }
    /// Release the lock
    ~APPNAME_PyLock()
    {
        if (_lock)
        {
            PyEval_ReleaseThread(_threadState);
            PyThreadState_Clear(_threadState);
                PyThreadState_Delete(_threadState);
        }
    }
private:
    bool _lock;
    PyThreadState* _threadState;
};


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

PyObject* pycall_Shutdown(PyObject* self, PyObject* args);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

PyMethodDef _SessionMethods[] =
{    
    {(char *)"writeOutput",         pycall_Shutdown,                METH_VARARGS, (char *)"Output to standard output stream."},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
};

PyObject* pycall_Shutdown(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{

cout<<"I am form shutdown"<<endl;
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        Py_Initialize();

            PyObject* _SessionModule = 0;
        PyEval_InitThreads();
        cout<<"CP5"<<endl;
        PyThreadState* threadState = PyThreadState_Get();
        cout<<"CP5.1"<<endl;
        _InterpState = threadState->interp;

        APPNAME_PyLock();

        cout<<"CP5.3"<<endl;
        _SessionModule = Py_InitModule3((char *)"ttsession", _SessionMethods, (char *)"Built-in module to run TTServer.");
        cout<<"CP7"<<endl;
        PyEval_ReleaseThread(threadState);
        cout<<"END OF EXECUTION\n\n\n";

        Py_Finalize();

        return 0;
}
```

**This is the content of batch file, which I use to build the application**

```
cl /c Try3.cpp /IC:\Python27\include
link /link -debug /OUT:"./lib/Try3run.exe" Try3.obj /LIBPATH:"c:/Python27/libs" python27.lib
cd /d %~dp0%
set PATH=%PATH%;%~dp0%lib
```

I am running with Python 2.7.8 (installed in c:\Python27 folder)

I have a folder named "**lib**" in the present folder. This contains files like 
**python27.lib, python27_d.lib.**

I have copied the **DLL** folder and **Lib** folder from **c:\Python27**, into a folder named **python** in the current folder

To run the file change directory into lib and then type "**Try3run.exe**"

The program is failing at checkpoint3 (CPlock3) in the function APPNAME_PyLock() before acquring the lock.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Is there anyway by which I can get rid of this trouble

**Note :** I am running this in visual studio command prompt